# Fixed content with push menu

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, fixed

I'm running into an issue with having a fixed menu header (on scroll) that has a push out menu panel. The problem:

- When you scroll, the bar shows fixed at the top, which is correct. However, when you click on the menu the panel slides out but doesn't show the mast header fixed to the left.

What I'm trying to do:

- Nav header shows fixed position after scroll.
- When you click on the the menu and are scrolled down, the menu stays fixed to the top and the menu panel pops out on the left;

Here is a testing page:
http://creativebyhamilton.com/testing/cfc/

Let me know if you can help...

Comment: It would be useful to show the code in your question and not just a link to your site. Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as shown here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- this being said, it looks like your check for scrollTop >=100 is never connecting when the menu is visible. Try adding a breakpoint in your js and inspecting the value of scrollTop when it's visible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it was difficult to create a code snippet based on the issue involving multiple aspects of the code. I can verify that the script is working even with the panel open. If you look at the live code, the script adds the class even when the panel is open.

Comment: It seems more to be an issue with how fixed positioning is working in this example. I wonder if the fixed position element is reading the panel on the right's position rather than the panel on the left.

Comment: Without seeing how your menu is defined, are you sure it is always getting the parent frame when calling $(window) ?

Comment: I don't think the issue is that the script isn't working. Currently the script is adding the class ".scrolled-nav" to the navigation div which is the what I'm looking for. For some reason though, the fixed position of the nav isn't working as I expected - staying at the top of the "#container" div

Answer (score 0):

The website you have shown is developed in a way that when you click the nav menu the nav menu pops from the right and the main body of your website wrapped under the `div` with `id='container'` animates to the left with transitions.

The only solution i see here is to delete the class `.pushy-open-right #container` from the stylesheet of the website.

Update : Don't delete the class `.pushy-open-right .pushy`. Obviously the pushy nav bar won't work. You have to delete `.pushy-open-right #container`.
That should disable the slide out animation for the main container of the body and just the nav bar should slide out.

Comment: Removing that class would make the push out panel not work. Are you able to clarify the issue a little more? Is there a way to make it so the nav sticks to the top of the container div, even with the push menu open?